# Show that $|f(z)|\leq \left|\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given is that $|a|<1$ and the transformation $$T\colon z\mapsto\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$$ This maps $B(0,1)$ onto $B(0,1)$. Now suppose for some $\epsilon >0$ the function $f$ is holomorphic on $B(0,1+\epsilon)$ and $f(a)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1$. Now I have to prove that for $|z|\leq 1$ $$|f(z)|\leq \left|\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\right|$$
This is what I did. I want to use the Schwarz-lemma. So I defined $h(z)=f(-T(z))$ with the property that $h(0)=f(-T(0))=f(-\cdot -a)=0$. And also $$|h(z)|=|f(-T(z))|=|f(w)|\leq 1$$ 
where $T(z)=-w$. So with the Schwarz-lemma I conclude that $|f(-T(z))|=|h(z)|\leq |z|$. Now I don't know how to show the actual desired inequality. I need help continuing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose that $S$ is the inverse map of $-T$. Then $|f(z)|=|f(-T(S(z)))|\leq |S(z)|$, right?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, thanks, it worked!